# "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted." - Apache Tomcat con Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, tomcat

Es la primera vez que uso Netbeans (y la primera vez que programo) y estaba utilizando un servidor apache tomcat EE para mi aplicación web. Funcionaba perfecto, hasta que noté que casi no tenía espacio en el disco C, y cambié varias carpetas de lugar (no recuerdo exactamente cuáles) desde el disco C hacia el disco D. A partir de entonces no pude lograr que volviera a hacer deploy. Bajé nuevamente el apache, lo descomprimí en la misma carpeta que estaba antes, y no funcionó. Los errores que obtengo son:

> 25-Dec-2020 12:06:32.203 SEVERE [main]
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point
> associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"] java.lang.Exception:
> Socket bind failed: [730048] Only one usage of each socket address
> (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

y a continuación

> 25-Dec-2020 12:06:32.205 SEVERE [main]
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to
> initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component
> [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
>
> Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler
> initialization failed
>
> Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] Only one
> usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is
> normally permitted.

Intente cambiar el "socket port" en el apache desde netbeans, al siguiente o a 2 más de lo que estaba predeterminado, pero tampoco funcionó. Cuando busco los errores en google, no logro comprender qué es lo que tengo que hacer.

Comment: Cuando mencionás "no logro comprender qué es lo que tengo que hacer", ¿a qué te referís? ¿Qué fue lo que ya encontraste y que no podés implementar?

Comment: ya reiniciaste? creo qeu dejaste corriendo el servidor :)

Comment: @Ruslan Lopez Si, ya reinicie 100 veces. Tambien reinstale el apache. 

@ padaleiana Me refiero a que busque esos errores en google, pero no entiendo qué tengo que hacer para resolverlos. 

Muchas gracias

Comment: y ya probaste a cambiarle el puerto?

Comment: Sisi, ya probe. tampoco funciono